# php 5.4 mysql extension not working

Tags: php, mysql, yum, centos5

I installed PHP 5.4.6 via Remi repo using yum (CentOS 5 64 bit)

I ran this as well "yum --enablerepo=remi --disablerepo=base,updates install php54-mysql" and it says it worked, but when i try to start PHP-FPM, it says this

```
>Starting php-fpm: [26-Sep-2012 21:28:09] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so' - libmysqlclient.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 
>[26-Sep-2012 21:28:09] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so' - libmysqlclient.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 
>[26-Sep-2012 21:28:09] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so' - libmysqlclient.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

i looked for "libmysqlclient.so.15" but all i found was "libmysqlclient.so.18" on the server

also if it helps im using nginx and mysql 5.5

Comment: You can install with apt-get(for Ubuntu I used this one) then move the .so file to the location that error message is pointing out.  It should work then. It gave hard time too.

Comment: i tried symlinking the libmysqlclient.so.18  to libmysqlclient.so.15 and it did not make any difference.  the libmysqlclient.so.18 is in the folder that the error is saying it can't find it from... same error occurs

Answer (score 0):

You may do this, find your php.ini file and add this variable(If exist and change it.):

```
extension_dir = "/path/to/some/folder"
```

then put your all .so files in `/path/to/some/folder` path.

then restart apache, test it

You may look this link, I had also hard time with php+mysql integration. https://askubuntu.com/questions/174509/connection-failed-to-open-the-db-connection-could-not-find-driver